# Ubuntu 12.04 error command not found

Tags: command-line

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop LTS on three Intel systems. All the three PCs are using the same kernel version (3.2.0-29-generic-pae). But I have a problem that when I compile and build my executable on one PC, it does not run on the other PCs and displays an error message "command not found". However, if the same code is rebuilt on the other PC, it runs successfully. 
How can I make my executable built on one PC to run on another PC with the same Ubuntu 12.04 Linux kernel?

Comment: Could you post some information about how you're compiling and linking your program?

Comment: `command not found` smells with a bad path.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a problem between a 32bit and 64bit architecture.

Is the CPU you're compiling your code on the same as the other machines you're trying to run it on?

If you're compiling your code on a 32bit machine and trying to run it on a 64bit installed version of Ubuntu this could be your problem.

To install 32bit libraries, allowing you to run 32bit executables on a 64bit install:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`